# PHP Manipulating MySQL Results?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I need some little help on a simple thing!

I have this table in my database, where I have a number of images stored, called "covers".

And then I have a table in HTML that displays the covers of this MySQL table inside one of it's cells.

Like this:

```
<td><a href="movie.php?id=<?php echo $idt + 1; ?>">
<?php echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($idt + 1['cover'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'" alt="Cover" style="max-width:300px;max-height:300px;" />';; ?></a></td>
```

And this is the code before

```
$req = mysql_query("select id, name, year, genre, cover from movies");
$dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
$idt = $dnn['id'];
```

But why doesn't it work when I try to dynamically change id by putting this?

```
$idt + 1;
```

Comment: `$idt + 1['cover']` is not even valid code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `$idt` will be an `id` fetched from the database. Incrementing that value will not automatically fetch another record. You'll need to build a loop to fetch multiple records.

Comment: this doesn't work, variables doesn't start with an integer `$idt + 1['cover']` . And it's not valid code.

Comment: What are you *trying to achieve* by increasing `$idt`? Are you trying to iterate through all the rows in your result set? If so, you need to use a different approach. Also note that `mysql_*` are depreciated functions.

Comment: @showdev then do I loop with while?

Comment: @sjagr Im trying to change record every time

Comment: I don't understand your wording.

Comment: @sjagr I'm trying to change cover in every new cell in my HTML cable, by using the $idt but it's not working

Comment: I think he is trying to achieve a loop over the result set

Answer (score 1):

In order to output data from multiple rows, I suggest using a loop like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) {

  ?><td>
    <a href="movie.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
      <img src="<?php echo htmlentities($row['cover'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" alt="Cover" />
    </a>
  </td><?php

}
```

Comment: Please use no mysql_* functions they are marked as deprecated, use mysqli_* instead

Comment: Agreed. However, this is an attempt to help the OP with his or her code, not advice on how to rewrite with more modern techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch a whole set of results and not just one id and increment it in the view. You should do a *foreach* loop on *$idt* like that:

```
foreach($dnn as $row){
$id=$row['id'];
$cover=$row['cover'];
$genre=$row['genre'];
//etc...
//now echo html with vars like this:
echo "<img src=\"$cover\"/>";
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, because $idt is an integer and not an array

Comment: my bad, I meant *$dnn*

Comment: I believe [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://us1.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) only fetches one row of the result set. So, as it's currently written, `$dnn` will only contain the first row of the set. You are looping through each column of the first row. You'll need to loop through the rows themselves, outputting data from each row.